# ESPER check if value is NaN

Tags: esper, nesper

Hej, does anyone know how I can check in ESPER if a value is NaN? I want to get the slope of some variables which works, but the first value is always NaN. I want to exclude that value.
`value ='NaN'` and
`value = NaN` does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try `Double.isNaN(...)`. On the JVM it is "Double.NaN!=Double.NaN" making "isNaN" the right choice.